# Record audio input directly to local storage

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive me in advance if this isn't possible as I'm usually a back-end developer. I'm looking to create a simple transcription tool. As a way to substantially reduce server cost I'm hoping to have the transcription take place on the client machine. The way I'm looking to do this is by recording audio input and immediately saving it to an IndexedDB and not sending it to the server. Is this possible with Javascript and or HTML5 and if so is there a plugin or tutorial to do so? I know there is a lot for recording and streaming to server where you can then download it to the client system but that is a ton of unnecessary overhead. I wanted to put it on something like an IndexedDB to hide it from the user to some capacity as well as provide a defined location for my script to look for the audio file. Thanks for any help!

Comment: _localStorage_ would need to be a _String_ so you'd have to encode into e.g. _Base64_, but there are other technologies you could use for binary data e.g. **[_IndexedDB_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)**

Comment: @PaulS. thanks, just updated question accordingly and will start looking into that!